# How to divide div diagonally without changing border?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create the following design:

[image]

I have tried the following:

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

#container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Vp7nW2SP6H8/maxresdefault.jpg);
}

#triangle-topleft {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 300px solid white;
  border-right: 300px solid transparent;
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="triangle-topleft">
      <p id="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ut bibendum justo
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-cherry-8do13?file=/src/styles.css:0-390) But this approach won't work with varying screen sizes. I need to divide div in two diagonally.
In the desired result there should be a `div` that is separated diagonally. Which contains two diagonal `div`. These two `div` contain data.
How can I achieve this?

UPDATE: I tried `clip-path` property.([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-butterfly-7vc4m?file=/src/styles.css:384-393)) But I still have to use `position:absolute`

Comment: Border can't be a percentage, which is what's tripping you up. But it can be a value of the view height or view width, i.e. 100vh for 100% of the viewport height. If you're trying to match the viewport width/height then perhaps this would work for your particular use case?

Comment: @Le-royStaines I don't want to use `position: absolute`.

Comment: what the issue with position:absolute?

Comment: The issue is setting the content for different screen sizes. For example, On laptop, we have various screen sizes. I can use `vw` but it doesn't guarantee content to look the same in all screen sizes.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-visvesvaraya-elw04

Comment: P.S. for the text to wrap within the diagonals, you could fudge it to set the width of the text content to a ratio based on the width/height of the parent container and the height of the content/text element.

Answer (score 0):

HTML doesn't do triangular divs, so you're going to have to fake it somehow, whatever you do. (Your text is never going to flow neatly in those triangular frames.) The solution may be to use a CSS gradient fill like this:

```css
.triangle {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #fff 0%, #fff 50%, green 50%, green 100%);
}
```

(taken from [Coding Dude](http://www.coding-dude.com/wp/css/create-a-triangle/))

That solution should cope with all sizes and aspect ratios of div. But you're going to have to do some hacky positioning to get the text frames to be positioned correctly.

Ultimately, you may have to accept that what you have here is a fixed-size design, and build your code accordingly, with different solutions for small screens.